# Check unique number in create method (DAO)

Tags: java, jpa, dao, crud

this is my create method:

```
public Person create(Person person) {
    if (person.getId() != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person already has an id.");
    }
    if (person == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person is null.");
    }
    if (person.getUniqueNumber() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unique number is null.");
    }
    if (person.getUniqueNumber().length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect unique number.");
    }
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(person);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return person;
}
```

And these are Person attributes:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String uniqueNumber;
}
```

How can I check whether uniqueNumber in create method (if there are no two people with the same unique number)?

Comment: This is using the JPA?

Answer (score 1):

You should either

1. have a unique constraint for 'uniquenumber' column in the DB. this is the easiest and most safe way. since it will handle concurrency. Exception will be thrown if you try to insert another user with the same uniquenumber of an already existing user.
2. inside create method have another DAO call to check if there is already a user with the same unique number. probably will need to have the correct transaction isolation level set for this to work properly.

I would recommend going for 1st approach.